# Sentence Transformation using "either ... or"

Tags: correlating-conjunctions

> Don't drive if you are drunk. If not, face the consequences.

Can I rewrite the given sentence by using " Either ... or " as:

> Either don't drive if you are drunk or face the consequences.

Comment: In example 1, I'd say "If *you do*, face the consequences".

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is grammatically incorrect; it would he correct to use "if you do", as CopperKettle suggested.

You can use the second sentence instead in spoken language - it is gramaticaly correct - but a more logical structure would be "if you are drunk, either don't drive, or face the consequences". It would be preferable in writing.